# Can "mongrel" be used to refer to people?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, pejorative-language

I'm translating a fantasy novel into English. In the story there are a bunch of races. Among them, there are mixed-race people. "Pure races" mock mixed-race people and usually refer to them as '*mongrels*'. Now, taking into consideration that this word is also used to describe dogs that live on the streets, would it be awkward for humans?

I picked this word intentionally to bring a bad connotation to mind; I want the reader to feel how prejudiced the races are. The original word is "mestiço" in Portuguese.

Comment: You can use the term, but be prepared for hate mail.  The word is highly pejorative and offensive to many.

Comment: Can you post the original word? It would be okay to do this for half breeds like half-orc, half-human, but I would stray *far* away from using it to describe any type of human.

Comment: Do the "Pure races" get called [inbred or pedigree](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/mongrel/antonyms) in return?

Comment: I think Mudbloods is taken.

Comment: Humans are just one of the races. The pure races (12 in number) are the ones that did not mix. Nevertheless, some of the them mingled with other races. They generated offspring. Their children were first caste and they are called half-breeds along the way.

Comment: Half-breeds' offspring (second caste) are called crossbreds throughout the story. I know "half-breed" and "crossbred" have the same meaning, but I just used them to distinguish the castes. Half-breeds and Crossbreds are called in general "mestizos" by the pure races. The third cast are hibrid, the mix of mixed races. They are the scum of the planet. So I decided to use the word mongrel exactly because I want the reader to feel how prejudiced the races are.

Comment: The original word is "mestiço" in Portuguese. The "pure races" are named according to their race (Humans, Eloha'ins, etc) or terms like "Houses", "Twelve Houses", etc.

Comment: Maybe I didn't read it carefully enough, but the Wikipedia article on Mestiços, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesti%C3%A7o, doesn't mention a derogatory connotation behind the word. It should, if the word has such a connotation.

Comment: Did you do a simple dictionary lookup? [All the online ones mention people](https://www.google.com/search?q=defintion+mongrel). That said, I would have said no, the primary denotation of 'mongrel' exclude people, but of course it can be used metaphorically for people.

Comment: Yes. Consulting a dictionary is always the first thing to do.

Comment: @EduardoGalvãoJunior You should edit and put your findings in your question, otherwise the is (re) closable as 'Please do research first'

Comment: You can't have all this information about the story hidden in the comments. Unless someone upvotes a comment, anyone who visits the page thinks the question lacks detail and context. What's more, it seems the inhabitants are not all humans. I think that is a pretty fundamental detail. The question reads ~...would it be awkward for humans?…~

Comment: Are humans "the mongrels" in this fictional land?

Comment: Pejorative? Maybe, but I feel there's too much emphasis on how bad it is. It isn't something that would be uttered or taken offensively except by someone with very select sensitivities and it certainly doesn't seem more offensive than calling someone a half-breed. There's a NZ biker gang who call themselves mongrels so...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Humans aren't called mongrels in the story. Not even the narrator calls them so. There is a particular race that I wanted to portrey them as racists. Having this in mind, every time one of them speaks, I don't use the common word "half-breeds", I use the word "mongrels" since I meant them to be depicted as prejudiced and racist people.

Comment: Then why did you put in the title "can mongrels refer to people"? And why did you allow the edit that asks "would it be awkward for humans?" It kinda changes the dynamics of the question and the answers are mostly focused on the element of human beings. I think it is too late now to edit, it would risk invalidating people's answers. Well, are you happy with the answer posted by @ab2? That's the most important thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I signed up and made a question. I didn't even know that people could edit my question. So, in this case I allowed simply because I didn't know. I found it strange when I saw my question edited with "would it be awkward for humans" because it has nothing to do with my doubt. Anyways, I'm newbie here. Still learning how it works.

And yes, I am happy with the help I got.

Comment: I just voted to close as unclear. Eduardo, I suggest you start fresh with a new question where you explain that you would like to translate *mestiço* to English, giving the context, similar to how you did in your question and comments here.  You should include at least one examples of narration and/or dialogue that will include the desired word.  For a question requesting a word, an example sentence is a required element. // What made this question especially badly posed, for me, was that you appeared to contradict yourself: You say you intentionally picked a word with a *bad connotation*;

Comment: ... yet you appear to want reassurance that it's not "awkward" (!).  If that doesn't seem like a contradictory stance to you, then maybe you should explain what you mean by "bad connotation" and "awkward."  It was also confusing to try to figure out who's human, who's not, who's calling who a mongrel and what you're trying to accomplish by choosing that word. // By the way, if *mestiço* is similar to *mestizo* in Spanish, it's emphatically not equivalent to *mongrel*.

Comment: In English, 'half-breed' is a term that only has extremely racist connotations in relation to humans. Please never use this term again to refer to the biology or ethnicity of humans.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Respectfully, I don't think this would be ok for any human-like group half ork or not.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Well, I guess I meant "Don't use it in real life," where we don't have orcs. If it's supposed to be an extremely offensive term in the book, then it might be appropriate.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Thanks. Yes, I understood that intent. I appreciated it too However, I really think it needs to be crystal clear for NNS that there's no situation where it's inoffensive to refer to people (of any type) as  *mongrels* or *half-breeds* unless one is trying to capture some other negative or worrying quality of the people using those terms. You're absolutely right that "*If it's supposed to be an extremely offensive term in the book, then it might be appropriate*".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yeah, I think the accepted answer addresses that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Green Grasso Holm said in her answer, mongrel **can** be used for a person.  But, as many others commented, it is an extremely offensive term when applied to a person.  (And it is an insult to many mixed breed dogs, who tend to be every bit as intelligent and fine in character as purebreds.)

**As long as you make it absolutely clear that this is a offensive term used by a racist society or by the bad guys in your story, you may get away with it.**

I wondered if Mr. Spock, half human and half Vulcan, was ever called a mongrel in Star Trek, so I asked on Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange: [Was Spock ever called a mongrel in a Star Trek TV episode or movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185071/was-spock-ever-called-a-mongrel-in-a-star-trek-tv-episode-or-movie)

The answer by @Buzz is **No**, although Spock was called a half-breed in three episodes. According to a comment by @wcullen, Spock was referred to as a mongrel in a non-canon novel *Shocks of Adversity*, but non-canon doesn't count among Star Trek aficionados.  Finally, there was an [interview with Leonard Nimoy](http://www.leonardnimoy.de/index.php/interviews/1172-reflections-on-spock-), who played Spock, in which he calls Spock a mongrel, but the wording is ambiguous and Nimoy may possibly be saying that Vulcans regarded Spock as a mongrel. Or not.

I've gone into all this detail on Spock **because he is the most famous mixed-species person in all of science fiction, perhaps in all literature**, and standards were much more lax when Star Trek came out.  So the conclusion is:

As far as the English goes, you **can** use it, but be careful if you **do** use it.

Comment: Your answer does not make it clear to the NNS involved that for native English speakers "half-breed" is racist slur when used in relation to humans, or is used by people who are so inherently racist that they don't realise that it's a slur. [That doesn't include NNS].

Comment: Worth pointing out that the term (half breed) was used by the author of the question, but it was recently edited out.

Answer (score 10):

It's a perfect word to describe a person of mixed origins if you intend for it to be pejorative.

Merriam Webster mentions its applicability to persons. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mongrel

> 1 : an individual resulting from the interbreeding of diverse breeds (see *breed 1*) or strains (see *strain 1*); especially : one of unknown ancestry *She owns several dogs, one of which is a mongrel.*
>
> 2 : a cross between types of persons or things.

Comment: It needs to be noted that its use in this sense is *extremely* offensive.

Comment: Exactly... I singled it out precisely to convey a bad idea.

Comment: @HotLicks Quite right. And it is only slightly less offensive to refer to "half-breeds". The polite term to use in this day and age is "a person of mixed race".

Comment: @HotLicks In the context, I think that is the intention.

Comment: @WS2 I disagree. I find *half-breed* to be even more offensive and aggressive than *mongrel*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. You may well be right. I would not dream of using either of them.

Answer (score -1):

I know, coming from the British Isles, after invasions from Anglos, Saxons, Normans and and Danes - to names a few. I don't regard myself as pure bred as I see the the Welsh - pure Britons to or the Scots or Bretons. I regard myself as a mongrel as an assimilation of mixed race. My Serbian wife and her family, however, despite the communist influence consider themselves as pure Serbian, despite the fact that the family come from Croatia and Bosnia. Mongrel is a proud badge to wear. . . .and it means we can celebrate all feasts, anywhere. But I still reserve the right to take the piss out of the Church of exclusivity. I love the feast of 25th December, a mixture is pagans and god bothered new year and the Orthodox festivals as well  - I get pissed to them all and really love Chinese New Year because it's on a different date Evey year. ...a kind of random bonus. . ...I can't wait for Ramadan to end. . . that's a really good piss up

Comment: Although quite interesting, I am not sure this over-sharing answers the Q...

Comment: Seems like you're saying "yes"? You've buried the lede and provide no supporting evidence. If you have the time, please improve the answer.